# OpenGLES to Metal migration

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, metal, metalkit

In OpenGLES, it is simple to crop & scale pixel buffer by using pass through shaders, and then setting

```
glViewport(0, 0, srcDimensions.width, srcDimensions.height)
```

followed by setting texture & vertex coordinates appropriately by using the cropRect, and then setting

```
        glActiveTexture( GLenum(GL_TEXTURE0) )
        glBindTexture( CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget( dstTexture! ), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName( dstTexture! ) )
        glTexParameteri( GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER), GL_LINEAR )
        glTexParameteri( GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER), GL_LINEAR )
        glTexParameteri( GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S), GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE )
        glTexParameteri( GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T), GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE )
        glFramebufferTexture2D( GLenum(GL_FRAMEBUFFER), GLenum(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0), CVOpenGLESTextureGetTarget( dstTexture! ), CVOpenGLESTextureGetName( dstTexture! ), 0 )
```

What is the equivalent setup for the same thing in Metal?